# Can't get C# RSA Decryption answer

Tags: c#, encryption, rsa

I am trying to encrypt and decrypt a string "Dilan" using C# RSA Encryption method. Although at the decrypting part I cannot get an answer. Then I use my keys in this page https://8gwifi.org/RSAFunctionality?keysize=2048 and try to get an answer.

From the encryption part,

```
Answer:
Decrypted plaintext: Dilan
Encripted plaintext: ODPcL+q4UaDlSo3CGBVww0DHnjv2AgBrr8gZD6HozQnyVoO03G01m9H/FAxQfiK9tFMRmxiMBMLnMMs53UxcSAa4XwCmOoxbOT6GeU+NUAIc1FtwckSQW+O/fB8Xg5OC2K7kaqX52Aa4xGN/I0yIXhJH7rrPHjUejbRnNeXOW1E=
```

For the https://8gwifi.org/RSAFunctionality?keysize=2048 page, I'm using

```
Public Key:
-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAjARAj29gfyS6C7sQSjsJ
ulPGa9RMSntxJHvJRZG3KSo5lLKVLzFnIv0h6AMUOMQ/e0aic3LOd742ebKrxQdD
RA/as/zEqPOTh7t6ahQok33gjcn6+DP95RMfj85n0Cdm1GV0AjFdBhkYf189u1De
w6sSwUF2PhEky3wki7jR1UKWl7y7h0HEmsYhaDATBJYSz+3u1N5aN0X5gysv5KoP
QJ7D8Y8qNwFZFM39TUgeB4ZFT/QR853adNLinZ8/6rnkFZQO1BSChFXC0+2hB7/Z
4h9RAziLPXenmATvk8vxXXothRcKrP2n/mY8YrBfiGM8rvENdo/xqW0WEsFvZEbI
ywIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----

Private Key:
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

String:
Dilan
```

C# Code:

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

namespace RSACSPSample
{


    class RSACSPSample
    {

        static void Main()
        {

            string publicKey = "<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>b1kOI/0aD04EL6brX81csy3xaSAKOezF1n/g+mbyTR4rYQMWl4QMiG8XHx8E1KgERNjenbwePO0YcqH0FJP01sDPfiqleLK7FcoXJ00K9COcBCOzBf3OlSmpGYaPQ00O9pMGxXjyOc8a/wef//dPXIeXBeTxMrkR99vScWyck5E=</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent></RSAKeyValue>";
            string privateKey = "<RSAKeyValue><Modulus>b1kOI/0aD04EL6brX81csy3xaSAKOezF1n/g+mbyTR4rYQMWl4QMiG8XHx8E1KgERNjenbwePO0YcqH0FJP01sDPfiqleLK7FcoXJ00K9COcBCOzBf3OlSmpGYaPQ00O9pMGxXjyOc8a/wef//dPXIeXBeTxMrkR99vScWyck5E=</Modulus><Exponent>AQAB</Exponent><P>zSih4lMrHGBRq6PJPvYGevP8WbKAnQwERYi25K2zAIUrUdSWVVOQ7UjuVC1Tfw1Hg57Wal+/jTXjUcmRPgJr0Q==</P><Q>ivEEhXTAwQ2ZnSoEpiSlMW8Q/s6SB4agafZPpKajiOjqWv9y4E0OV1ZFe0GcbQlGgLAmfyWr5TgBYtr+ZJZbwQ==</Q><DP>izD2JEepCCeRQZJuB3mEDAddPr4M5IAypbqL27q9p6yyJ2LEXD/GJDdG+3WFIL4xtusdLi6oF3ZoNCU9lYSvAQ==</DP><DQ>D/Jt1Gt8HCxVb0Z9VhxqoWvgBX7sH9UB4GeW6Iz/xB0HmP4szzXI6ZlLTERRkeo4n1iYcot+WUa+UfxUqnLfgQ==</DQ><InverseQ>keZ+2rPqijIf0uW7MK7v9OHw7+eecPxXbbZAlDNxIUZeMdPuAR/JBUPPS2rqvIb0BJG28dwyaSAIaSfxqJoH4g==</InverseQ><D>SHIY0TGMEwkfkCF6Ywqqlan+t/cwsB9tWPI63rC8VZCbiLMJr+sqfFpLIOR9sB7hKCoyLU6IHfvlPDBDLmBVm8RVC9ytaUQewNj9cD5AB+YKGgh6p2oXpY7WcSRxgjqGIc2klPj3zyTrBn247kde3n5sD+wFY9KCTjPfllhpwAE=</D></RSAKeyValue>";

            try
            {
                //Create a UnicodeEncoder to convert between byte array and string.
                UnicodeEncoding ByteConverter = new UnicodeEncoding();

                //Create byte arrays to hold original, encrypted, and decrypted data.
                byte[] dataToEncrypt = ByteConverter.GetBytes("Dilan");
                byte[] encryptedData;
                byte[] decryptedData;

                //Create a new instance of RSACryptoServiceProvider to generate
                //public and private key data.
                using (RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
                {

                    //Pass the data to ENCRYPT, the public key information 
                    //(using RSACryptoServiceProvider.ExportParameters(false),
                    //and a boolean flag specifying no OAEP padding.
                    encryptedData = RSAEncrypt(dataToEncrypt, publicKey, false);
                    var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(encryptedData);
                    //Pass the data to DECRYPT, the private key information 
                    //(using RSACryptoServiceProvider.ExportParameters(true),
                    //and a boolean flag specifying no OAEP padding.
                    decryptedData = RSADecrypt(encryptedData, privateKey, false);

                    //Display the decrypted plaintext to the console. 
                    Console.WriteLine("Decrypted plaintext: {0}", ByteConverter.GetString(decryptedData));
                    Console.WriteLine("Encripted plaintext: {0}", base64);
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException)
            {
                //Catch this exception in case the encryption did
                //not succeed.
                Console.WriteLine("Encryption failed.");

            }
        }

        public static byte[] RSAEncrypt(byte[] DataToEncrypt, string publicKey, bool DoOAEPPadding)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] encryptedData;
                //Create a new instance of RSACryptoServiceProvider.
                using (RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
                {

                    //Import the RSA Key information. This only needs
                    //to include the public key information.
                    RSA.FromXmlString(publicKey);

                    //Encrypt the passed byte array and specify OAEP padding.  
                    //OAEP padding is only available on Microsoft Windows XP or
                    //later.  
                    encryptedData = RSA.Encrypt(DataToEncrypt, DoOAEPPadding);
                }
                return encryptedData;
            }
            //Catch and display a CryptographicException  
            //to the console.
            catch (CryptographicException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.Message);

                return null;
            }

        }

        public static byte[] RSADecrypt(byte[] DataToDecrypt, string privateKey, bool DoOAEPPadding)
        {
            try
            {
                byte[] decryptedData;
                //Create a new instance of RSACryptoServiceProvider.
                using (RSACryptoServiceProvider RSA = new RSACryptoServiceProvider())
                {
                    //Import the RSA Key information. This needs
                    //to include the private key information.
                    RSA.FromXmlString(privateKey);

                    //Decrypt the passed byte array and specify OAEP padding.  
                    //OAEP padding is only available on Microsoft Windows XP or
                    //later.  
                    decryptedData = RSA.Decrypt(DataToDecrypt, DoOAEPPadding);
                }
                return decryptedData;
            }
            //Catch and display a CryptographicException  
            //to the console.
            catch (CryptographicException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());

                return null;
            }

        }
    }
    }
```

Comment: _"Although at the decrypting part I cannot get an answer."_ - What? What does that mean?

Comment: This given c# code gives encrypted output but I cannot decrypt it using  https://8gwifi.org/RSAFunctionality?keysize=2048 with the private key. @John

Comment: @John There is no exception in the code but output can't be decrypted by the given website ** https://8gwifi.org/RSAFunctionality?keysize=2048 **